# What is the best SIMPLE replacement for VS Setup-project Installer for WinXP + WPF + .NET 4.0?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, installation, windows-xp

I'm having troubles installing my WPF application on Windows XP (required to be updated with SP3 and .NET 4.0 preinstalled).
My installer is made with Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project.

Question: What is the best simple installer product to replace the VS-Setup one?
In particular, I would prefer not to...

- create complicated XML config/install files.
- spend a whole week learning some rare scripting language.
- spend a lot of money for a very basic install process.

Also, can developer with experience in installing WPF applications on WPF give opinion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the free version of [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). It's oriented towards usability, so it should be easy to use.

It doesn't support prerequisites, but it does support launch conditions (stop the installation and show an error if a requirement is not met). It also has a Visual Studio extension which can be integrated in your solution.

You can also try some of these tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

As a side note, a Windows Service Pack is a very important and very big update. It's not recommended to add it as a prerequisite, but it can be added as a launch condition.

Answer (score 2):

I always used InstallShield. Pricey, but AFAIK the "free" InstallShield LE is included with VS 2010.

WiX is available on Codeplex (http://wix.codeplex.com), but it is *very* complex.

You can compare all 3 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee721500%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

For bonus points - I used this once, I think: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Features