# Should I incorporate a setup wizard at first run, or use an MSI?

Tags: c#, forms, installation, wizard

My program has a handful of settings that need to be established before it can operate correctly. I would like the user to be shown a setup wizard either at first run or at install that has them set everything up to their needs. Right now my program does not use an installer, it just runs from its exe file. The program does offer the option to change these settings when it is running, however I want the user to set the settings first before the program runs. My options seem to be:

1. Use a setup wizard (either my own or one created such as this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignTimeWizard.aspx).)
2. Make the program use an MSI and install. Several have pointed out that an MSI will allow for a program set up while installing which would satisfy the need I have.

As an MSI option sounds like it is the norm for programs I should perhaps learn about those. But I am still curious for other peoples input on this particular problem. For those who are going to recommend the MSI solution, I'm new to this particular aspect of programming, any recommended links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you find a "predesigned" wizard?

Comment: you could look at converting that into a .MSI project with that it also would add the necessary Install/UnInstall as well as icons in the add/remove programs for you..

Comment: Would making the project an MSI make it easy to set up a wizard for first run?

Comment: an MSI would mean that you would see a setup wizard on install not on first run. I would say that this is the best way to do things as its the way every other program works. Having a setup wizard on first run is against the normal convention so it will annoy people

Comment: If you have a "predesigned" wizard - whatever that is - why not use it? Better to use somebody else's work than your own.

(Actually, I think you're looking for an Options menu in your executable that lets your users configure the application - but I'm not sure whether you are in control of the application)

Perhaps you need to rephrase your question, I think a lot of us have problems with it.

Comment: I tend to release a lot of updates or betas to a couple testers, does an msi allow for updating easily or would each revision require the previous version to be uninstalled and then a new install and set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it really depends on what your application deployment does. If it simply copies some files and registry entries an MSI will handle most of your needs, including upgrades. Here is a similar discussion which may help you: [What is the best SIMPLE replacement for VS Setup-project Installer for WinXP + WPF + .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729495/what-is-the-best-simple-replacement-for-vs-setup-project-installer-for-winxp-w)

If your deployment process involves custom and/or complex tasks, a customized wizard is better because it gives you more control. MSI packages are very limited when it comes to customization.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar:

Whenever the application is launched, we check the settings storage (usually a database) and if anything needs to be set, we launch the setup wizard.

If the user cancels the setup for some reason, the application is terminated, meaning that the user can't proceed to the main application until the initial configuration is complete.

Having spent an inordinate amount of time configuring (or attempting to configure) installers (Installshield, Installaware, etc), I can promise you that this is the most effective, efficient way to accomplish your goal.

There are some things that you should (and in some cases, have) to do in the installers, but from your description, they don't apply to your situation.

Comment: I have a free trial of installshield but don't know what the terms of use are for it. As this is opensource software I'm not looking to make a big investment of money into it. Would you recommend a particular installer over another?

Comment: The only installer that I have extensive experience with is installshield and it is very expensive. They have an express version, but that starts at $590. Unless you absolutely have to, I wouldn't recommend using an installer for this. I can't tell you how many weeks I have wasted trying to get everything to work correctly. It is much, much easier to do what you are looking for in your own code.